# The maven assembly plugin moduleset sources instructions are not including any files and not matching the included modules

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project, and I'm trying to get the moduleset sources portion of the assembly plugin to work.

I have modules "**module_parent**", "**module_a**", and "**module_assembly**".

**module_a** and **module_assembly** are children of **module_parent**.

**module_assembly** has a declared pom dependency on **module_a**.

**module_assmebly** has the assembly plugin, with the assembly.xml looking like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<assembly>
  <id>bin</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
      <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
      <includes>
        <include>com.mystuff:module_a</include>
      </includes>
      <sources>
        <fileSets>
          <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/target/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <directory>/</directory>
          </fileSet>
        </fileSets>
      </sources>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
</assembly> <!-- -->
```

**I have an explicit dependency in module_assembly for module_a.  The dependency in module_assembly's pom looks like:**

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mystuff</groupId>
        <artifactId>module_a</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The error I get from mvn package with debug turned on is:

```
[DEBUG] All known ContainerDescritporHandler components: [metaInf-services, plexus, metaInf-spring, file-aggregator]
[DEBUG] No dependency sets specified.
[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter:
o  'com.mystuff:module_a'

[DEBUG] Cannot find ArtifactResolver with hint: project-cache-aware
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver
  roleHint: project-cache-aware
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:257)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:233)
        at
  <snip>
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Collections$EmptyIterator.next(Collections.java:3006)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:253)
        ... 43 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
<snip>
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2:single (make-assembly) on project apm-server-distribution: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive bin: You must set at least one file. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2:single (make-assembly) on project apm-server-distribution: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive bin: You must set at least one file.
```

I think the main problem is this warning line:

```
[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter:
    o  'com.mystuff:module_a'
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: yes, it does have an explicit dependency.  I included it above in the 2nd set of "code" formatting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If module_assembly doesn't have a child reference to your module, it's not counted as a module.  Note the content here refers to children only: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-module-set-topics.html

If you want to do this, you need to use a dependencySet rather than a moduleSet.

PS - Thank you for the bounty!

Comment: but dependencySet only allows for jar files to be included, right?  What I'm after are some loose xml and properties files floating around in src/main/resources in other modules.

Comment: You can use fileSet to include non JAR files.

Answer (score 2):

I was just debugging the assembly plugin, because I have a similar problen, and I think that the problem is `<useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>`. On top of that, there is also the tag `<includeSubModules>`, which is probably what you want.

```
<assembly>
  <id>bin</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
      <useAllReactorProjects>false</useAllReactorProjects><!-- Or just don't remove this line -->
      <includeSubModules>true>
...
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
</assembly
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me using the following configuration:

```
  <includeSubModules>false</includeSubModules>
  <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying does not work, since **module_a** is not a submodule of **module_assembly**.

Here are some ideas of what you can do:

- Include the relevant files into the jar (maybe the source plugin helps) and use dependencySet.
- Change your module structure, such that **module_assembly** is the parent and **module_parent** and **module_a** are submodules. Of cource, the dependency structure remains as it is.
- Just use a fileSet in the assembly with relative paths that point into the other project (ugly!)