# Maven OSGi project compiles, but won't run

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx, osgi

I have been trying to port [Paul Bakker's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1195938/paul-bakker?tab=badges&sort=class) (**@paul-bakker**) [Making JavaFX better with OSGi : **javafx-osgi-example**](http://paulonjava.blogspot.co.ke/2014/11/making-javafx-better-with-osgi.html) to a maven OSGi project that uses the Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin (BND). So far it compiles without any errors, but I can't get it to run:

```
Starting OSGi Framework
Found declarative services implementation: file:/C:/Users/Rev/.m2/repository/org/apache/felix/org.apache.felix.scr/1.6.2/org.apache.felix.scr-1.6.2.jar
INFO : org.apache.felix.scr (1):  Version = 1.6.2
Bundle: org.apache.felix.framework
    Registered service: [org.osgi.service.resolver.Resolver]
    Registered service: [org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin]
    Registered service: [org.osgi.service.startlevel.StartLevel]
Bundle: org.apache.felix.scr
    Registered service: [org.apache.felix.scr.ScrService]
    Registered service: [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService]
    Registered service: [org.apache.felix.scr.impl.ScrGogoCommand]
DEBUG: Starting ComponentActorThread
Bundle: null
Bundle: null
Bundle: null
```

As you can see, the bundles never get started. No errors are thrown. It just simply doesn't start.

Why won't the bundles start?

**THE PROJECT SOURCES**

> 1. > [Paul Bakker's (The original non-maven project) : javafx-osgi-example](https://github.com/paulbakker/javafx-osgi-example)
> 2. > [My maven implementation of Paul Bakker's **javafx-osgi-example** : JavaFX-Maven-Multi-Module-OSGi](https://github.com/TryRevilo/JavaFX-Maven-Multi-Module-OSGi)

From the terminal (Windows), mvn clean install works perfectly.

**UPDATE**

I've been trying to run it from Eclipse, but to no success:

> Run -> Run as -> Java Application

---

> Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
>
> Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
> Build id: 20160218-0600

---

**UPDATE**

I have a class `App` under **dist** in the package `rev.dist` that does the launching. It goes loops throug all the directories under the **rev** and starts any jars whose names match the names under `resources/plugins.txt`.

APP.java

```
package rev.dist;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleException;
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference;
import org.osgi.framework.launch.Framework;
import org.osgi.framework.launch.FrameworkFactory;

public class App {

    FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory;
    private Framework framework;

    private List<String> pluginsList = new ArrayList<>();

    private int addedPlugins;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BundleException, URISyntaxException {
        App app = new App();
        app.initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() throws BundleException, URISyntaxException {
        this.plugins();

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // make sure the cache is cleaned
        map.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN, Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN_ONFIRSTINIT);

        map.put("ds.showtrace", "true");
        map.put("ds.showerrors", "true");

        frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();
        framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(map);

        System.out.println("Starting OSGi Framework");
        framework.init();

        loadScrBundle(framework);

        File baseDir = new File("../");
        String baseDirPath = baseDir.getAbsolutePath();

        File[] files = new File(baseDirPath).listFiles();

        this.showFiles(files);

        for (Bundle bundle : framework.getBundleContext().getBundles()) {
            bundle.start();
            System.out.println("Bundle: " + bundle.getSymbolicName());
            if (bundle.getRegisteredServices() != null) {
                for (ServiceReference<?> serviceReference : bundle.getRegisteredServices())
                    System.out.println("\tRegistered service: " + serviceReference);
            }
        }
    }

    public void showFiles(File[] files) throws BundleException {

        if (addedPlugins != pluginsList.size()) {
            System.out.println(":: " + pluginsList.size());
            addedPlugins--;
        }

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                // System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getName());
                showFiles(file.listFiles()); // Calls same method again.
            } else {
                String[] bits = file.getName().split(".");
                if (bits.length > 0 && bits[bits.length - 1].equalsIgnoreCase("jar")) {
                    // framework.getBundleContext().installBundle(file.toURI().toString());
                }

                // String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getAbsolutePath());

                String basename = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getName());

                if (pluginsList.contains(basename)) {
                    framework.getBundleContext().installBundle(file.toURI().toString());
                    System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());

                    System.out.println("Base >>>>>>>>>>>>> : " + basename);

                    pluginsList.remove(basename);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void plugins() {
        File plugins = new File("src/main/resources/plugins.txt");
        String fileName = plugins.getAbsolutePath();

        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName))) {

            // br returns as stream and convert it into a List
            pluginsList = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        pluginsList.forEach(System.out::println);
        addedPlugins = pluginsList.size();
    }

    private void loadScrBundle(Framework framework) throws URISyntaxException, BundleException {
        URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("org/apache/felix/scr/ScrService.class");
        if (url == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not find the class org.apache.felix.scr.ScrService");
        String jarPath = url.toURI().getSchemeSpecificPart().replaceAll("!.*", "");
        System.out.println("Found declarative services implementation: " + jarPath);
        framework.getBundleContext().installBundle(jarPath).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: mvn clean install does not work perfectly. The ui pom declares a dependency on rev.launcher:launcher:1.0-SNAPSHOT and the mainscreen pom declares a dependency on rev.ui:ui:1.0-SNAPSHOT. The group Ids of the launcher and ui modules that are currently being built are simply 'rev'. I think you renamed the group Ids after running mvn install and are picking up old versions from you local repository.

Comment: The assembly descriptor used in dist uses moduleSet but other the other modules are children of the rev:rev top level pom. I think you need to use dependencySet see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310482/the-maven-assembly-plugin-moduleset-sources-instructions-are-not-including-any-f . Could you update the question with more detail about how to build and run your code?

Comment: How are you launching it? There is almost no information here...

Comment: Hi @Neil Bartlett I have a class `App` under **dist** in the package `rev.dist` that does the launching. It goes loops throug all the directories under the **rev** and starts any jars whose names match the names under `resources/plugins.txt`. I did an update to the question with `App.class`

Comment: Okay the code is fairly long and confusing so I'm not going to bother working out exactly what it does. However the basic pattern of: (1) install all the bundles, then (2) start all the bundles, is sound. So perhaps there is just a bug in the code. Have you tried running in a debugger? BTW why do you need to separately install and start the SCR bundle? Note that that bundle does actually start so there may be a clue here.

Answer (score 1):

I have released a couple of first Early Access versions of [Drombler FX](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/) - the modular application framework for JavaFX.

It's not based on Paul Bakker's work, but it's based on OSGi and Maven (POM-first), as well. Maybe you find it useful. The application framework is Open Source.

There is also a [tutorial](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/current/docs/tutorial/index.html) with a [Getting Started](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/current/docs/tutorial/getting-started.html#gettingStarted) page.